Web push, pushsubscriptionchange browser support?
I am trying to understand browser support for event pushsubscriptionchange.
I found this old blog post of Chrome (2016) saying that support starts from version 54.
On MDN page it's reported that only Safari desktop fully supports it.
CanIUse reports that only Safari desktop and Safari iOS supports it, while Chrome has never done.
Blog post from SitePoint 2018 seems to say that the event is widely supported.
web.dev (which is Google) on teaching how to handle subscription expiration does not cite it.

What part of those links don't you udnerstand?

@Jaromanda X I can't get a clear overview about browser support fort this feature. e.g Chrome blog says it supported from version 54, CanIUse says Chrome never supported it

I would generally trust MDN and CanIUse, it seems like Chrome was planning to release it but ran into a bug and never got back to it, so that blog post was probably written before support was pulled.
